# Store Jsonstring using Entity Framework Core ExecuteSqlRawAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity in which for one of the string field I want to store jsonstring (json equivalent of List of MyObject) using EF Core `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` extension.

However, I am getting this error :

> Input string was not in a correct format.

from EF at

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RawSqlCommandBuilder.Build.

I am using EF Core version 3.1.

Please find below an overview of sample similar to what I am trying:

```
string query = "update mytable set column1 = 100, column2= '[{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":null}]' where condition;update mytable set column1= 200, column2= '[{\"property1\":\"value2\",\"property\":null}]' where condition;"

await this.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query);
```

If I run the same raw SQL statement directly against the SQL Server database, it works just fine.

Is there some limitation in the `RawSql` extension that string field in an entity cannot have jsonstring?

Any help how to run raw query with one of the string entity field accommodating jsonstring?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is caused by the `'{'` and `'}'` symbols inside SQL string, because in `ExecuteSqlRaw{Async}` they are used to specify parameter placeholders, so the string should be a valid input for `string.Format` function. In fact EF Core implementation uses `string.Format` (even though you don't pass parameters) at some point, which in turn generates the exception in question. Which can be seen if you do

```
string.Format(query);
```

The solution is to make it valid format string by doubling `'{'` and `'}'` symbols inside. For instance, in your sample:

```
string query = "update mytable set column1 = 100, column2= '[{{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":null}}]' where condition;update mytable set column1= 200, column2= '[{{\"property1\":\"value2\",\"property\":null}}]' where condition;"
```

Also it would be good if you try actually parameterizing your SQL.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. In my case, single query statement may contain many entities with same set of parameters but different values (similar to example in question). I am not sure if there is a clean approach to pass parameters in raw query for such scenario. problem statement here is mapping set of parameters against parameter place holders of each statement part of same query. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Different value means different parameter. Just replace the embedded literals with placeholders "pointing* to the values as you would do with `string.Format`. e.g. `var ags = new List<object> { 100, 200 };` then  `var query = "... column1 = {0}, ... column1 = {1} ..."; `  and finally `ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query, args)`